# POEDIT : Impossible to set up the right path

Tags: macos, path, directory, poedit

I run under Max OSX.

I've installed Poedit in /Applications.

The website I have to translate is located in /Dropbox/Sites/mywebsite.

In Poedit preferences I've got to set up the base path and the path of the website. I tried many combinations and each time Poedit tells me something like "no code has been found"...

Do you know how to set up the right path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of others that may stumble upon this question, the correct solution is to set it up as follows:

1. The "base path" should be a path *relative to the PO file location*, e.g. ".." or ".". If you must, and don't care about portability to other computers, use an absolute path there, but not elsewhere.
2. The other paths in PO file properties, *must* be relative to the base path and should be under the base path in the tree (i.e. the base path should be the "root").

For example, you could save PO files under languages/ and have basepath=".." and "src" and "includes" paths.

**EDIT:** In modern versions of Poedit (1.8 and up), you don’t have to worry about this. Just drag the paths you want to the source paths window and Poedit will generate correct settings automatically.

Comment: I just have some questions regarding ```BasePath``` and ```SearchPath```. ```BasePath``` is the location to the ```messages.po``` file and ```SearchPath``` is the root directory where the gettext functions are being used for translation?

Comment: My project directory is ```C:\xampp\htdocs\api``` (this is were Poedit look for translation) and ```messages.po```  directory is ```C:\xampp\htdocs\api\i18N\locale\es\LC_MESSAGES```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

Base path should be : "."

Website path should be : "/Users/USERNAME/Dropbox/Sites/mywebsite"

That's it! ;-)

Comment: This is wrong. All the paths should be *relative* — the paths should be relative to the base path and if at all possible, the base path itself should be relative to the location of the PO file. Using absolute paths makes the PO file unportable to another computers.

Comment: I see what you mean, but in my case I don't share the file, so it works for me. Thanks.

Comment: As the Poedit author, I can authoritatively tell you that having "." as the base path and then absolute paths in place of the base-relative ones does *not* always work correctly, e.g. when OS X sandbox is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I had a folder **Catalogue->Properties->Sources Paths->Path**, but this folder did not existed physically (was deleted).

It was the folder **CRON/** in the picture. Simply removing the **CRON/** folder in the Paths solved the issue (see picture).

Obviously, you can add back the **CRON/** folder also.

[image]